# Disable scrolling after Holding event was raised

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, flipview

In my WP8.1 app I have a FlipView with some FlipViewItems. One of these Items has a Grid set as content. I want to achieve that when I tap and hold this Grid, the scrolling of the FlipView immediately stops. 
By setting the `ScrollMode`, `ScrollbarVisibility`, `IsEnabled` or `ManipulationMode` I could only achieve that the scrolling is disabled after I ended the touch (move finger away from the display). But moving the finger away from the screen and back on again is no good UX...
Has anybody an idea how to solve this?
(I think it is somehow related to this problem:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6a10367-479c-472c-95e5-ddd6f05a76f4/listview-touch-input-disable-vertical-scrolling-once-holding-event-has-been-raised?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Comment: Solution was the CancelDirectionManipulations method. More info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.canceldirectmanipulations.aspx